# Как отобразить объект, созданный с помощью createElement, 12 раз

Tags: javascript, dom, style, for

Нужно отобразить созданный квадрат 12 раз, используя цикл и чтобы каждый квадрат нумеровался от 1 до 12. Не понимаю, почему не выходит

```js
    let a = document.createElement('div');
    let div = document.getElementById('kappa');
    a.style.cssText = 'width:20px; height:20px; background-color:red;';
    for(let i = 0; i<12; i++){
        div.appendChild(a);
    }
```

```html
<div id = 'kappa'></div>
```

Comment: `div.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));` - так будет работать,смею предположить что  Ваш вариант не работает так происходит попытка вставить один и тот же элемент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не выходит, потому что элемент создается только один раз. Чтобы добавить 12 элементов, соответственно и создать нужно 12 элементов) А значит надо пихнуть их внутри цикла for, чтобы на каждом круге создавать новый элемент, так:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/47rz1tbn/)

```js
let a;
let div = document.getElementById('kappa');
for(let i = 0; i < 12; i++){
  a = document.createElement('div');
  a.className = 'moo';
  a.innerText = (i+1);
  div.appendChild(a);
}
```

```css
.moo {
  width: 50px; height: 50px; display: inline-block; 
  margin: 4px; background-color: #045acf; color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="kappa"></div>
```